# Centralize API Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, .net-core

We have this project to create a so-called "API Interface" which will be serve as a centralize application to retrieve the data from different source system via SOAP or REST API. The requirement is that, this API Interface should be applicable to all source system.

Currently, we have received the wsdl file from one of the source system. I converted it into Service.cs file and use this to call their web service via HTTPBinding.

My question is that, possible to develop 1 application that should be applicable to all source system having different web service or wsdl file or either the system is using restapi? Because, currently we dont know yet what could be the structure of the other source system. But, neverthless, the incoming source system should be able to use the so-called "API Interface", without updating the source code.

Hoping you understand my question/problem. Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: The answer to this question is "it depends". Lest's say that you want to create API interface for managing users from different platforms by using their API then you probably would be able to do some create/get user endpoints which would work on each of them. But there will be also functions which won't be in each of these services so you will not be able to implement one universal method for them. Like creating auctions on ebay vs creating posts on twitter for example

Comment: I bet you could do something like this but it would all need to be configuration based. Not straight forward though.